# C# - Can you call an Enum by the number value?

Tags: c#

If I have this code

```
//Spice Enums
enum SpiceLevels {None = 0 , Mild = 1, Moderate = 2, Ferocious = 3};
```

Which states the Enum Names + Their Number, how can I call an enum from a variable, say if a variable was `3`, how do I get it to call and display Ferocious?

Comment: As answered you can just cast the `int` value. But keep in mind that an `enum` can have multiple times the same value. In this case, the first element would be returned.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just cast the integer to the enum:

```
SpiceLevels level = (SpiceLevels) 3;
```

and of course the other way around also works:

```
int number = (int) SpiceLevels.Ferocious;
```

See also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except char. The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int.
>
> ...
>
> However, an explicit cast is necessary to convert from enum type to an integral type

Answer (score 2):

```
enum SpiceLevels { None = 0, Mild = 1, Moderate = 2, Ferocious = 3 };
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 3;
    Console.WriteLine((SpiceLevels)x);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums inherit from Int32 by default so each item is assigned a numeric value, starting from zero (unless you specify the values yourself, as you have done).

Therefore, getting the enum is just a case of casting the int value to your enum...

```
int myValue = 3;
SpiceLevels level = (SpiceLevels)myValue;
WriteLine(level); // writes "Ferocious"
```